# Can we now find boost 1.48.0 on yum in Fedora 16?

Tags: fedora, yum, boost

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but I really cannot find any information on the Web. Boost 1.48.0 has been out on the website for two days but there has still been no update on yum. I just want to make sure if everything is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a bug/feature request to [upgrade to 1.48.0 for Fedora 17](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=754865). There was a similar one to [upgrade to Boost 1.47.0 for Fedora 16](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=711845) that mentions Boost 1.48.0 wouldn't be released in time for Fedora 16. It looks like you'll have to wait for Fedora 17 to get Boost 1.48.0.

A [page on the wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/F17Boost148) also has more info on Boost 1.48.0 for Fedora 17.

Comment: Thanks! Very quick answer! Seems we need to wait till Fedora 17...

Comment: @derekhh: Not necessarily. You can (probably) rebuild your current Boost source rpm to use the newer Boost. The only problem would be if the source is extensively patched.

Answer (score 0):

Note that **two days** is not a significant amount of time for an update to get into a stable/released distro. ... it's asking a lot even for Fedora.